# Is there a way to send a file over bluetooth using j2me and ftp protocol from a mobile to a pc

Tags: ftp, bluetooth, java-me

I am making a j2me application to send an image (taken from a camera) to a PC for further processing. Can I send it over bluetooth using ftp to the pc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use JSR-82, you can connect a mobile and PC using Bluetooth and send/receive using input/output streams for the wireless transfer, and link those streams to reading and writing your files.

The J2ME GCF supports Bluetooth using URLs such as btspp:// and btl2cap:// URLs to open connections. There's a good introduction on Bluetooth programming [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothintro/). Or even better, there's a tutorial on using OBEX for transferring images [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothobex/).

Bear in mind, to do Bluetooth on a desktop PC (in Java SE), you will need a JSR-82 implementation for the desktop to interface with your Bluetooth chip - you can use something like [Bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) (free) or [Avetana](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml) (non-free).

Comment: Why can't JSR-82 suffice for interacting with the desktop bluetooth chip, just as it does for the mobile bluetooth chip?

Comment: The point is that Sun Microsystems does not implement JSR-82 for Java SE, so it's simply not present in the Standard Edition JRE or JDK. JSR-82 in J2ME is implemented only on handsets, where in the Java ME SDK the emulator does not provide any 'real' hardware interface with a desktop Bluetooth chip. That's why you need a third-party implementation such as those I listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for FTP too, but I used OBEX and avetanaOBEX implementation for transferring files.

Answer (score 1):

I found an excellent example of how to connect PC and J2ME Mobile phone in this blog.

[mobile-programming-and-games_java-connect-pc-and-mobile-phone-over](http://mobile-programming-and-games.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-connect-pc-and-mobile-phone-over.html)

and include code source for testing!...

Check this video

[youtube_iiM0C5cx_H0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiM0C5cx_H0)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not FTP, but you'll want to take a look at [JSR-82](http://www.jsr82.com/), the Java Bluetooth APIs.  Tutorials are available at that site.

Comment: While sending files from the pc to any mobile device using bluetooth, the dialog box which shows up mentions FTP. How do I implement the same in J2ME while send files from a mobile device to the pc